# EL expression does not get null key from map: #{bean.someMap[trd.type].label} where trd.type is null

Tags: jsf-2, enums, null, hashmap, el

We're (ab)using enums for our application mainly for multilingual purposes, for example:

```
public enum ETradingSector
{
    EMPLOYEE ( "M" ),
    CUSTOMER ( "C" ),
    NOSTRO   ( "N" ),
    FUND     ( "F" ),
    UNDEFINED( null ); // HashMap allows null keys (if used)

    public static final Map<String,ETradingSector> map;

    static
    {
        map = new HashMap<>();

        for ( ETradingSector enm : ETradingSector.values() )
        {
            map.put( enm.getFlag(), enm );
        }
    }

    private final String flag;

    // "com.company.some.package.ETradingSector.<enum_name>.label" to find resource bundle string
    private final String labelKey = getClass( ).getName() + "." + name() + "." + NamingConventions.LABEL_KEY_SUFFIX;

    private ETradingSector( String flag )
    {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    public String getFlag()
    {
        return this.flag;
    }

    public String getLabel()
    {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle( Constants.DEFAULT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE_NAME, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale() ).getString( this.labelKey );
    }
}
```

This enum hosts a `Map<String,Enum>` to translate a `String`-valued DB flag into an enum value *which do not equal*. It's an important detail to note that we don't want to use enum names like M, C, N, F (simply because some dweeb put German-language flags into the DB eons ago). This is also the reason why we don't map these enums on our JPA entities via `@Enumerated` (we're using JPA 2.0, where differing DB and enum names aren't possible).

In any case, we're displaying a JSF datatable and one of our columns contains an EL expression to display the trade type multilingually, like

```
"#{enumValuesProvider.mappedTradingSectors[trd.type].label}"
```

The column is supposed to display the localized label or "Undefined" where the trade type is null per trd. -> The `trd` var is the current row variable of the datatable (actually a PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable ... var="trd" ...>`).

In our message property files, we have a convention being (here `_en.properties`):

```
com.company.some.package.ETradingSector.CUSTOMER.label  = Customer
com.company.some.package.ETradingSector.EMPLOYEE.label  = Employee
com.company.some.package.ETradingSector.FUND.label      = Funds
com.company.some.package.ETradingSector.NOSTRO.label    = Proprietary
com.company.some.package.ETradingSector.UNDEFINED.label = Undefined
```

To manually map the `String`-typed field on our JPA 2.0 entity

```
public Trade implements Serializable
{
    ...

    @Column( name = "NOSTRO_FLAG", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private String type; // can be "M", "C", "N", "F" or null

    ...
}
```

to a multilingual enum with a differing name (which JPA 2.0 cannot do out of the box), we defined an `EnumValuesProvider` CDI bean to access the mapped enum's `getLabel()` method:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class EnumValuesProvider implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ...

    public Map<String,ETradingSector> getMappedTradingSectors()
    {
        return ETradingSector.map;
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem now is: whenever the `trd.type` for a row is null, the expression `"#{enumValuesProvider.mappedTradingSectors[trd.type].label}"` results in an **empty cell** instead of showing the string "Undefined", even though the map has a `null` key entry to the `UNDEFINED` enum.

[image]

When I change the map creation to add an empty string mapping like

```
    static
    {
        map = new HashMap<>();

        for ( ETradingSector enm : ETradingSector.values() )
        {
            if ( enm.getFlag() == null )
            {
                // if flag is null, add null AND empty string mappings
                map.put( null, enm );
                map.put( "", enm );
            }
            else
            {
                map.put( enm.getFlag(), enm );
            }
        }
    }
```

and change the value expression to

```
"#{enumValuesProvider.mappedTradingSectors[not empty trd.type ? trd.type : ''].label}"
```

the cell is displayed correctly:

[image]

Something seems to be wrong accessing null `Map` keys, but empty strings seems to work.

**QUESTION/S**:

What's happening here? Why is the `UNDEFINED` enum **not** being picked up by the EL when `trd.type` is null? (We're using Mojarra 2.1.22...)

Comment: Is the changing of the value expression really necessary?

Comment: Yes. The map with `null` and empty string alongside `#{enumValuesProvider.mappedTradingSectors[trd.type].label}` renders an empty cell.

Comment: Heh. Using the expression `#{enumValuesProvider.mappedTradingSectors.get(trd.type).label}` renders the cell with "Undefined"... do we have a Mojarra issue now?

Comment: This is recognizable as EL 3.0 bug, but then that value expression would theoretically not have been necessary. Which EL impl/version are you using?

Comment: I think EL 2.2. We're on GF 3 with Java EE 6 stuff.